# Jade : Short version of if then

Tags: conditional-statements, pug

I have this code which works

```
if (activePage === 'index')
    a.active(href="index.html") Index
else
    a(href="index.html") Index
```

I'd like to short it with something like :

```
- var vclass = #{activePage==='popol' ? 'active' : ''};
a(class=#{vclass}) Index
```

or better something like

```
a(class=#{activePage==='index' ? 'active' : ''}) Index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code should work and is better

```
a(href='index.html' class=activePage === 'index' ? 'active' : '') Index
```